# Using XPATH to select from a specific range of repeated nodes

Tags: java, xpath, hl7

I am attempting to parse a document that has the following (much simplified) structure.  Each document could have one or more ORB segments each followed by one or more OBX segments.  The OBX segments relate directly to the preceeding OBR segment.

```
<obr> ...... </obr>
<obx> ...... </obx>
<obx> ...... </obx>
<obx> ...... </obx>
<obr> ...... </obr>
<obx> ...... </obx>
<obx> ...... </obx>
```

The following is a more detailed though still simplified example:

```
<OBR>
    <OBR.1>
        <OBR.1.1>1</OBR.1.1>
    </OBR.1>
    <OBR.2/>
    <OBR.3>
        <OBR.3.1>12345678</OBR.3.1>
        <OBR.3.2>PLS</OBR.3.2>
    </OBR.3>
    <OBR.4>
        <OBR.4.1>CRP, LFT, Ue</OBR.4.1>
        <OBR.4.2>C Reactive protein, Liver Function Tests, Urea, Elec, Creat</OBR.4.2>
        <OBR.4.3>PLS</OBR.4.3>
    </OBR.4>
</OBR>
<OBX>
    <OBX.1>
        <OBX.1.1>1</OBX.1.1>
    </OBX.1>
    <OBX.2>
        <OBX.2.1>NM</OBX.2.1>
    </OBX.2>
    <OBX.3>
        <OBX.3.1>CRP</OBX.3.1>
        <OBX.3.2>C-Reactive Protein</OBX.3.2>
        <OBX.3.3>PLS</OBX.3.3>
    </OBX.3>
</OBX>
```

I need to develop and xPath expression / Java code that can extract  text from a specific OBR segment together with the muliple  text.  It is straight forward to extract the index'th OBX.3.2 in the entire document using:

```
public Object read(String expression, QName returnType, int index) {
    expression = "(" + expression + ")[" + Integer.toString(index) + "]";
    try {
        XPathExpression xPathExpression = xPath.compile(expression);
        return xPathExpression.evaluate(xmlDocument, returnType);
    } catch (XPathExpressionException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

But I am not sure how to find the index'th OBX.3.2 associated with say the second OBR or indeed how to count the number of OBX segments for each OBR (If I new this I could probably solve the problem).  Any guidance or advice would be much appreciated.

I have also tried the Kayessian method ($ns1[count(.| $ns2)=count($ns2)]) to count elements giving:

```
count( //OBR[3]/following-sibling::OBX [ count (.|//OBR[4]/preceding-sibling::OBX) = count(//OBR[4]/preceding-sibling::OBX )])
```

This expression gives the number of OBX elements below the indexed OBR and the next OBR.  It does not however correctly handle the last OBR in the group (as there is no ORB after it)

Comment: "count the number of OBX segments for each OBR" Could you please clarify how those two elements are related?

Comment: An OBR can be thought of as a "header".  It contains administrative information about the tests that follow.  The OBX elements contains test results.  A single OBR can be followed by 0 to n OBX elements.  A single document can have multiple OBR's - I hop this makes it a little clearer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case others stumble across this:  The solution to counting the segments is fairly simple:

To count OBX after the i'th OBR:

```
count(//OBR[i]/following-sibling::OBX) - count(//OBR[i+1]/following-sibling::OBX)
```

It is then possible to loop through the appropriate segments using the reader code above.

Answer (score 1):

I would transform the original XML to a more convinient form with XSLT and deal with the result.

An example XSLT transformation:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

<xsl:template match="OBR">
    <xsl:variable name="$cur_OBR" select="."/>
    <xsl:variable
        name="obx"
        select="following-sibling::OBX[preceding-sibling::OBR[1] = $cur_OBR]"/>

    <OBR position="{position()}">
        <xsl:for-each select="*/*">
            <xsl:variable name="suffix"
                          select="substring-after(name(), 'OBR')"/>
            <xsl:variable name="rel_obx"
                          select="$obx/*/*[ends-with(name(), $suffix)]"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="sub_OBR">
                <xsl:with-params name="suffix" select="$suffix"/>
                <xsl:with-params name="rel_obx" select="$rel_obx"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </OBR>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="OBX"/>

<xsl:template mode="sub_OBR" match="*">
    <xsl:param name="suffix" select="substring-after(name(), 'OBR')"/>
    <xsl:param name="rel_obx"/>

    <xsl:element name="concat('OBR', $suffix)">
        <OBR>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="text()"/>
        </OBR>
        <xsl:for-each select="$rel_obx">
            <OBX>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="text()"/>
            </OBX>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I have not run it though to check if it is absolutely correct. You can see also that you would need a variable to select corresponding OBX elements for an OBR with xpath: `following-sibling::OBX[preceding-sibling::OBR[1] = $cur_OBR]`.

Comment: thank you newtover - I had not considered this possibility.  I will need to read up on translations.  My only thought at this stage would relate to managing changes to the upstream provider - but I guess that is the case anyway.